# Increment Loop in Batches

Tags: r, loops, raster, r-raster

I was hoping someone could help me with a loop function I'm working with. I have tried searching Google and Stack Overflow extensively but, as I don't know the exact search terminology, I fear I am missing some results. With that in mind, I apologise in advance if this question has already been asked but I hope that someone can point me in the right direction for a solution.

**About My Data**

I have downloaded 1000s of files from NASAs MODIS satellite. As my study area covers a large area, I've had to download the data over an area of 6 tiles. As a result, my list of downloaded files are actually 'grouped' together in bunches of 6 (despite appearing as just a list of files within explorer).

I have written some simple for loops within R to do some initial processing (in the example below this is to resample the tiles so that they can then be stitched together using raster::mosaic. This processing can happen on the files individually at this stage so I have found the below loop to be perfect for my needs:

```
resampled.raster<-list()

for (l in 1:24){
  cat(l,"\n")
  resampled.raster[[l]]<-resample(rst[[l]], s, method="ngb")
}
```

**The Problem**

The next stage of my processing requires me to mosaic the rasters in groups of 6, before moving onto the next batch of 6. For example, if I have a list of 24 files, the first 6 will need to be processed as a collection of files and then saved (in a list) before moving to the next 6. After 4 iterations of this (to make the 24 files total), I need the loop to stop.

The closest solution I have found from searching the internet is [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-August/170370.html) but this isn't a solution to my problem.

Is this 'batch' processing possible with using a for loop within R? Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I've never used `raster` but to select a batch you can do something like: `step <- 6` with `for(i in seq(1,24,step ))` and then inside the loop `batchIndex <- i:(i+step)`

Comment: you could make .txt file with a list of file names grouped by batches

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. RobertH's solution below is working and I have accepted this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that it is almost certainly wrong to use `resample` and `mosaic`. If these are tiles, you should be able to use `merge` to merge them.

There surely is something unique about the names of the files that need to be grouped? That is what you need to use.

Get a vector with filenames

```
# ff <- list.files()
```

Here a toy example

```
ff <- c('fileA1', 'fileA2', 'fileB1', 'fileB2')
```

Get the unique groups

```
code <- gsub('file', '', ff)
code <- substr(code, 1, 1)
uc <- unique(code)
```

Loop over the groups

```
for (u in uc) {
    files <- ff[u == code]
    r <- lapply(files, raster)
    r$filename <- paste0("merged/", u, ".tif")
    m <- do.call(merge, r)
}
```

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you very much for your assistance. This is a really elegant solution and it has worked perfectly. I'm still new to programming so a detailed answer like this has really helped me to understand what's happening. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: In case anyone in future will find this helpful, here is some extra information. As RobertH asks, there is something unique about the file names. Each file is named something like:

MOD15A2.A2016169.h09v07.005.2016183085001


Using Robert's code detailed above I removed "MOD15A2." and proceeded to use the next 8 characters in the file name as the unique identifier (in this case it's A22016169)

As my data span 6 tiles across the globe, there are six files each containing A2016169. These were the 6 files that were merged.